# Value of $\int_{|z+1|=2} \frac{z^2}{4-z^2}dz$

Tags: complex-analysis

$\int_{|z+1|=2} \frac{z^2}{4-z^2}dz=-2\pi i$.

Am  I correct, I used cauchy integral formula

[image]

Comment: Clockwise or counterclockwise?

Comment: not specified in question.

Comment: Which did you assume?  It's more common to assume counterclockwise

Comment: I did not consider any orientation and simply applied cauchy integral formula.

Comment: This means you assumed the same orientation as in the Cauchy integral formula. That formula has some assumptions attached to it; forget them at your own risk.

Comment: If the contour is traversed counter-clockwise, then your answer is incorrect.  If the contour is traversed clockwise, then your answer is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $z^2-4=(z-2)(z+2)$ and $z=-2$ is the only zero inside $|z+1|=2$. Assuming $|z+1|=2$ is positively oriented, Cauchy's Integral Formula gives 
$$
\int_{|z+1|=2}\frac{z^2}{4-z^2}dz =- \int_{|z+1|=2}\frac{z^2}{z^2-4}dz = -\int_{|z+1|=2}\frac{z^2}{(z-2)(z+2)}dz =- 2 \pi i \left( \frac{z^2}{z-2} \right)_{z=-2} = 2\pi i
$$
Hence your result is not the correct one! If $|z+1|=2$ is negatively oriented, then you have the correct result!

Answer (score 1):

i think you should first take the negative sign common from the denominator then use Cauchy Integral formula to proceed.